# If $\nabla f({x_0},{y_0}) = 0$then Can we say that differentiability in $(x_0,y_0)$ is lost?

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x,y)$ be a polynomial and (gradient of $f$) $\nabla f({x_0},{y_0}) = 0$.

Can we say that differentiability in $(x_0,y_0)$ is lost?

Comment: No, we can only say that the gradient is zero. If f was not differentiable in that point, we wouldn't be able to calculate the gradient in the first place. Fortunately, all polynomials are infinitely differentiable everywhere.

Comment: We know if all the partial derivatives of $f(x,y)$ exist in an open neighbourhood around $(x_0,y_0)$ & the partials are continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$ then we know $f$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: @rt6 - Suppose $f$ be polynomial and we know differentiability in $(x_0,y_0)$ is lost, in this case can we say $\nabla f({x_0},{y_0}) = 0$?

Comment: @Undersky: It may hold true that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_{(x_0,y_0)}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}|_{(x_0,y_0)}=0$ even when $f$ is not differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$ since it could be one of the other directional derivatives aren't well behaved. 

But it wouldn't be useful to know this. And it certainly won't be true in general that  $\nabla f({x_0},{y_0}) = 0$ if we know $f$ is not differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$

Comment: @Undersky: But your initial assumptions are contradictory in this case, we cannot have a polynomial $f$ being non-differentiable at any point.

Comment: @rt6 It was a new question, in comment 3

Comment: @Undersky: Yes, but "Suppose $f$ be polynomial and we know differentiability in $(x_0,y_0)$ is lost" - these assumptions are at odds with one another. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial - Always differentiable is the defining property of a polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_{(x_0,y_0)}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}|_{(x_0,y_0)}=0$ since $\nabla f({x_0},{y_0}) = 0$

So both partials exist at $(x_0,y_0)$.

Given $f(x,y)$ is a polynomial so it's differentiable at all points, hence its continuous at all points, in particular $(x_0,y_0)$.

So $f$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$.